# Set User Agent in Playwright is not working

Tags: c#, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-sharp, playwright-dotnet

I am trying to set the user agent of playwright browser while initializing the browser context but it seems that it ignores the param I am giving and starts it with the default agent

could anyone point out what is the problem here?

version : **playwrightSharp v0.180.0**

```
private static Task<IPage> InitializePlayWrightPage()
        {
            var page = MarketsHelper.browser.NewPageAsync(userAgent:Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            return page;
        }
```

Comment: PlaywrightSharp is deprecated in favour of `Microsoft.Playwright`: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro. Update to the newer library, and if that doesn't fix it then log an issue in their GitHub repo.